# Problem with str_replace()

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have this code:

```
var_dump(format_currency($product_tax = $prodotto->getFinalPrice() + $product->getTax()));
var_dump(str_replace(" ", "", format_currency($product_tax = $prodotto->getFinalPrice() + $product->getTax())));
```

And it outputs this:

```
string ' 333,88' (length=8)
string ' 333,88' (length=8)
```

Why doesn't work ok the str_replace function?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but this is *terrible* code to debug. Please take the calculation operations out of the format_currency calls.

Comment: I don't think format_currency is a standard function. Did you write it? How does it work?

Comment: Why don't you use **trim**? Your `str_replace` should work though...

Comment: Possibly because the currency character isn't a space charater, but another invisible character such as a non-breaking space. Assign the result of your format_currency() to a variable (eg $tmp)... and then echo ord($tmp{0}); to see what the value of that character is

Comment: Even better, supply the code for `format_currency` in the question.

Comment: @Mark Baker: the echo ord($tmp{0}) outputs "194". Sorry because my code..So what should i do to remove the space?

Comment: I'd expect char(194) to be visible in your string... what charsets are you using?

Comment: So there's a good chance that it's an invisible multibyte character... let's see the code for your format_currency() function, so we can tell where the value is coming from

Comment: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/NumberHelper#method_format_currency

Comment: You're not passing the any currency code into the format_currency() function, which means that it default to NULL... so a trim() should work... although you should also get a 0 for ord($tmp{0}) rather than 194 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `trim` - the blank space may not actually be a blank space - it could be a number of other things.

```
var_dump(trim($yourString));
```

Comment: Not that trim() will pick up on most white-space characters, but doesn't remove the extended ASCII chr(160) which is a nbsp character

Comment: True, but in that case you could do this: `trim($yourString, chr(0xA0));`

Comment: @xl3 - that would be how to solve it, yes! I only mentioned it because I've been bitten in the a*** by it in the past when using trim() and assuming that white space was white space

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using symfony. Rather than trying to account for the invisible character (blacklisting), which could change depending on the default culture, why not simply whitelist?

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9\.,]/i', '', format_currency(...));
```

This will remove anything that isn't a number (0-9) comma (,) or decimal point (.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use number_format()

```
$value = number_format($product_tax = $prodotto->getFinalPrice() + $product->getTax(), 2, ',');
// the ',' will force the decimal charecter to be ','

var_dump($value)  --> string '333,88' (length=7)
```